# cambio de valor de textView dependiendo de la seleccion de un spinner

Tags: java, android, android-studio, spinner, textview

el problema planteado es el siguente , en la actividad tengo un `textView` y un `spinner` lo que busco es que cuando se seleccione una opcion en el `spinner` el valor del `textView` cambie .

Este es el codigo

```
public class longitud extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tex1, tex2, tex3;

    EditText valor;

    private TypedArray textview;
    private TextView textView;

    private String[] listOfObjects;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_longitud);

        tex1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tex1longitud);
        tex2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tex2longitud);
        tex3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tex3longitud);

        valor = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1longitud);

        listOfObjects = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.object_array3);

        textview = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.object_array_3);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1logitud);

        Button btconvertir = (Button)findViewById(R.id.botonlongitud1);

        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerlongitud);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listOfObjects);
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

        btconvertir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()) {
                    case 0 :
                        /**
                         * case EMPTY TO SPINNER TITTLE
                         * **/

                        break;

                    case 1:
                        /** cm to ft
                         *
                         * formula d(ft)=d(cm)/30.42
                         **/

                        if (!(valor.getText().toString()).isEmpty()) {
                            double valor_1 = Double.parseDouble(valor.getText().toString());
                            tex1.setText("d(ft)=d(cm)/30.42");
                            tex2.setText("d(ft)=" + valor_1 + "cm/30.42");
                            double resu = valor_1 / 30.42; /** centimeroFtConstante valor de 30.42 **/
                            tex3.setText("d(ft)=" + valor_1 + "cm");
                        }

                        break;

                    case 2 :
                        /** cm to pulg
                         *
                         * formula d(")=d(cm)/2.54 */

                        if (!(valor.getText().toString()).isEmpty()) {
                            double valor_1 = Double.parseDouble(valor.getText().toString());
                            tex1.setText("d(inc)=d(cm)/2.54");
                            tex2.setText("d(inc)=" + valor_1 + "cm/2.54");
                            double resu1 = valor_1 / 2.54;
                            tex3.setText("d(inc)=" + resu1);
                        }

                        break;

                    case 3 :
                        /**
                         * cm to mm
                         *
                         * formula d(mm)=d(cm)*10
                         * */

                        if (!(valor.getText().toString()).isEmpty()) {
                            double valor_1 = Double.parseDouble(valor.getText().toString());
                            tex1.setText("d(mm)=d(cm)*10");
                            tex2.setText("d(mm)=" + valor_1 + "cm*10");
                            double resu1 = valor_1 * 10;
                            tex3.setText("d(mm)=" + resu1);
                        }

                        break;

                    case 4:
                        /**
                         * ft to cm
                         *
                         * formula d(cm)=d(ft)*30.48
                         * */

                        if (!(valor.getText().toString()).isEmpty()) {
                            double valor_1 = Double.parseDouble(valor.getText().toString());

                            tex1.setText("d(cm)=d(ft)*30.48");
                            tex2.setText("d(cm)=" + valor_1 + "ft*30.48");
                            double resu1 = valor_1 * 30.48;
                            tex3.setText("d(cm)=" + resu1);
                        }

                        break;

                    case 5 :
                        /**
                         * feet to mm
                         *
                         * formula d(mm)=d(ft)*304.8
                         * */

                        if (!(valor.getText().toString()).isEmpty()) {
                            double valor_1 = Double.parseDouble(valor.getText().toString());
                            tex1.setText("d(mm)=d(ft)*304.8");
                            tex2.setText("d(mm)=" + valor_1 + "ft*304.8");
                            double resu1 = valor_1 * 305.8;
                            tex3.setText("d(mm)=" + resu1);
                        }

                        break;

                    case 6:
                        /**
                         * feet to inches
                         *
                         * formula d(inch)=d(ft)*12
                         * */

                        if (!(valor.getText().toString()).isEmpty()) {
                            double valor_1 = Double.parseDouble(valor.getText().toString());
                            tex1.setText("d(inch)=d(ft)*12");
                            tex2.setText("d(inch)=" + valor_1 + "ft*12");
                            double resu1 = valor_1 * 12;
                            tex3.setText("d(inch)=" + resu1);
                        }

                        break;

                    case 7 :
                        if (!(valor.getText().toString()).isEmpty()) {
                            double valor_1 = Double.parseDouble(valor.getText().toString());
                        }

                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                textView.setText(textview.getResourceId(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition(), -1));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola prueba realizando el siguiente cambio en tu codigo :

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        //aqui ya teniendo la posicion del objeto seleccionado vamos a buscar su valor a la lista que cargo el spinner :)
        textView.setText( listOfObjects[position] );


    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

Espero te sirva.
Saludos

Comment: gracias con ese me pude guiar

Answer (score 1):

En lugar de un `OnClickListener` en el botón,

```
btconvertir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()) {
```

debes configurar un [OnItemSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html) en el `spinner`:

```
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerlongitud);
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listOfObjects);
spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                /**
                 * case EMPTY TO SPINNER TITTLE
                 **/

                break;

            case 1:
                /** cm to ft
                 *
                 * formula d(ft)=d(cm)/30.42
                 **/

                if (!(valor.getText().toString()).isEmpty()) {
                    double valor_1 = Double.parseDouble(valor.getText().toString());
                    tex1.setText("d(ft)=d(cm)/30.42");
                    tex2.setText("d(ft)=" + valor_1 + "cm/30.42");

                    double resu = valor_1 / 30.42; /** centimeroFtConstante valor de 30.42 **/
                    tex3.setText("d(ft)=" + valor_1 + "cm");
                }

                break;
            case 2:
                /** cm to pulg
                 *
                 * formula d(")=d(cm)/2.54 */
                if (!(valor.getText().toString()).isEmpty()) {
                    double valor_1 = Double.parseDouble(valor.getText().toString());
                    tex1.setText("d(inc)=d(cm)/2.54");
                    tex2.setText("d(inc)=" + valor_1 + "cm/2.54");
                    double resu1 = valor_1 / 2.54;
                    tex3.setText("d(inc)=" + resu1);
                }

                break;
            case 3:
                ...

                break;

            case 4:
                ...

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución a mi problema. Funcionó de esta forma:

```
private String[]  listOfObjects2;

listOfObjects2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.object_array_3);

textView.setText( listOfObjects2[position] );
```